# how to display data in two column with php with header

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

I have database

```
---------------------------------------------
no | name   | code |  grade 
---------------------------------------------
1  | john   | A1   | C
2  | john   | A2   | D
3  | john   | A3   | B
4  | tom    | A1   | A
5  | john   | A4   | A
6  | alice  | A1   | C 
7  | alice  | A2   | D
8  | john   | A5   | D
9  | john   | A6   | C
---------------------------------------------
```

when I want show data with name john, I want result with 2 column:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
no | name   | code   |  grade | no | name   | code   |  grade |
---------------------------------------------------------------
1  | john   | A1     | C      | 5  | john   | A5     | D      |
2  | john   | A2     | D      | 6  | john   | A6     | C      |      
3  | john   | A3     | B      |    |        |        |        |
4  | john   | A4     | A      |    |        |        |        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

this my code that I already try

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from grade ");

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
echo "<td>no</td>";
echo "<td>name</td>";
echo "<td>code</td>";
echo "<td>grade</td></tr><tr>";

$no = 1;
$count = 1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);

    echo "<td>$no</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[code]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[grade]</td>";

    if ($count++ % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $no++;
    }
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```

But the result not what I want, this is the result when I run my code

---

```
no | name   | code   |  grade |    |        |        |        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
1  | john   | A1     | C      | 1  | john   | A4     | A      |
2  | john   | A2     | D      | 2  | john   | A5     | D      |      
3  | john   | A3     | B      | 3  | john   | A6     | C      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can somebody help me...thank you

Comment: have you tried anything yet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is representation problem, so it can be solved it two ways. 
**1.** You can make this columns using [modern HTML](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count):

```
<section style="-webkit-column-count:2; -webkit-column-gap:15;">
    <div class='columns'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>no</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>code</th>
                <th>grade</th>
            </tr>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select * from grade ");
$no = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$row['no']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['code']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['grade']}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    $no++;
}
?>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

**2.** If you want to stick to plain tables, you have to do some calculations:
First, you need to know full amount of grades you gonna show. You can get it with SQL query(more efficient way), I'll do it by preloading all data to array. HTML footer and header are omitted for brevity.

```
<?php
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM grade;');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$rows = (int) ceil(count($data)/2);

for ($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $no = $i + 1;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$no}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i]['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i]['code']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i]['grade']}</td>";
    if (array_key_exists($i + $rows, $data)) {
        $no = $i + $rows + 1;
        echo "<td>{$no}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data[$i + $rows]['name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data[$i + $rows]['code']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data[$i + $rows]['grade']}</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept correct answer :) Ofc, I hope it will be mine :)
And feel free to ask for clarification - I would like to improve my answer, if it's possible and required.

Comment: i try u'r code no.2, but there is error. Output :
1johnA1C
Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer 
 2johnA2D

Comment: Yes, there was a little bit unexpected for me ceil() function behavior - instead of int it returns float. So I added explicit to int conversion. I also fixed all typos. So now it's working with my php54 interpreter :)

Comment: Did you add header and footer which I omitted for second (and which you can take from first example)?
This is what you should see(I created some dummy data for this example): http://s23.postimg.org/n9glm1s8r/Screen_Shot_2015_02_12_at_09_54_26.png
I posted full code with dummy data here: https://gist.github.com/dorantor/dfdd1435c4097b26486b

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this nor checked for errors, but I think it is on the lines of what you are trying to accomplish.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from grade ");
$orig_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ( $orig_count % 2 != 0 )
     $count = $orig_count + 1;

$cols = $count / 2; 

//draw header
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
echo "<td>no</td>";
echo "<td>name</td>";
echo "<td>code</td>";
echo "<td>grade</td></tr><tr>"

for ( $i = 0; $i < $cols; i++ )
{
     if ( $orig_count == 0 )
          break; //zero results

     //first column    
     echo "<td>$i</td>";
     echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i, "name" )."</td>";
     echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i, "code" )."</td>";
     echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i, "grade" )."</td>"; 

     //second column
     if ( $i > $orig_count )
     {
          echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";   
     }
     else
     {
          echo "<td>".$i+($count/2)."</td>";
          echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i+($count/2), "name" )."</td>";
          echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i+($count/2), "code" )."</td>";
          echo "<td>".mysql_result( $result, $i+($count/2), "grade" )."</td>";   
     }
}

//finish off
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: -1 for: there's errors in your code, you didn't try to test it and for drawing the header only once when it's required to be drawn twice